# how to set delay between each tests in a testng.xml file

Tags: automation, selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

i'm new to testng.i want to run a test on a parallel execution mode.i'm using 
`selenium grid,
selenium webdriver,
testng`.

my testng.xml file is:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="WebDriver Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
<test name="WebDriver Test" >
    <parameter name="browser" value="firefox" />
    <parameter name="port" value="5555" />
<classes>
   <class name="BootUpTest" >
        <methods>
            <include name = "testBootUp"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
</classes>
</test>    
<test name="WebDriver Test for IE" >
    <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
    <parameter name="port" value="5556" />
<classes>
   <class name="BootUpTest" >
        <methods>
            <include name = "testBootUp"/>
        </methods>
    </class>
</classes>
</test>  
</suite>`
```

in the above xml file i supposed to run the `testBootUp` method in a`firefox` as well as `chrome`.i was able to run the above scenario.but my scope is i want to run the "**WebDriver Test**  test as first and then i need some delay after that only my **WebDriver Test for IE** test should have to run..

is it possible to achieve that in the testng.xml file?.

Comment: `@ A.J.` i designed framework as after finished the test execution it goes and write the result in the Excel sheet.In the above case the two tests are running simultaneously so while one is opened and  editing the sheet another one is trying to open the sheet..so at that situation it is showing `IO Exception`.

Comment: Putting a delay will not help in that case I think. How much delay will you put? Ideally you should wait till the first method is done writing. May be you should look at ways to store the results in memory and write it at the end of the test suite?

Comment: ya i thought to do that idea only..because of my curiosity i asked is it any option is available intestng for delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in `testng.xml` but why not put a `sleep()` in one of the before methods? (probably `@BeforeMethod`)?

Comment: thanks for your response cedric. But if i put sleep means i think it wont affect the thread which one is running parallel.

Comment: Well, your question says "how to set delay between each tests in a testng.xml file"... You might want to open a different question if ordering is what you are trying to accomplish.